Kernel Regression, Similarity-Based Modeling & Weights Normalization
Let be $D=[x_j(t_i)]_{i,j} \ M_{n,p}(\mathbb{R})$ a state matrix of $n$ $x(t_i) \in M_{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ observations of $p$ sensors $X_j$ representing the normal conditions of a system for some timesteps $t_1, ..., t_n \in T_n \subset T$.
The linear estimator of the Similarity-Based Model is :
$$ \forall \tau \in T \ \ \hat{x}(\tau) = w^*(\tau)^T \cdot D \in M_{1,p}(\mathbb{R}) $$
such that $w^*(\tau) = \text{argmin}_w || w^T \cdot D - x(\tau) ||^2$
Considering the error function $E_\tau:w \mapsto || w^T \cdot D - x(\tau) ||^2$ and its gradient, one can show that :
$$ \nabla E_\tau (w) = 2 w^T \cdot D\cdot D^T - 2 x(\tau) \cdot D^T $$
$$ w^* (\tau)^T =  (x(\tau)\cdot D^T) (D\cdot D^T)^{-1} $$
Now, considering the Kernel Trick, a much higher dimensionality space $\mathcal{H}$ with its inner product $\left \langle . | .  \right \rangle$ and a map function $\phi \in \mathcal{H}$, we can use a kernel operator $\otimes$ and a kernel function $K$ such that :
$$ K(u, v) = u \otimes v^T = \left \langle \phi(u) | \phi(v) \right \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} $$
$$ K(u, V) = u \otimes V^T =  [\left \langle \phi(u) | \phi(v_j) \right \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}]_{1\leq i\leq r} $$
$$ K(U, V) = U \otimes V^T =  [\left \langle \phi(u_i) | \phi(v_j) \right \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}]_{1\leq i, j\leq r} $$
Where $u, v \in M_{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ and $U, V \in M_{r,p}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $r \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$.
And then come up with the following formula :
$$ w^* (\tau)^T = (x(\tau) \otimes D^T)\cdot (D\otimes D^T)^{-1} $$
That is,
$$ \hat{x}(\tau) = (x(\tau) \otimes D^T)\cdot (D\otimes D^T)^{-1} \cdot D $$
The last formula does not involve any normalization of the weights where as the paper of the Similarity-Based Model does. Could someone help me reframe the problem (without getting too theoretical, I'm more focused on applied math) so I can understand what's missing? I grasp the concept of weight normalization, but I'm not sure how it applies in this specific formula.
My idea to reframe this problem is to add an equality constraint :
$$ \text{Find  } w^*(\tau) = \underset{\underset{\left \| w \right \|^2 = 1}{w \in \mathcal{M}_{n, 1}(\mathbb{R})}}{\text{argmin}} E_\tau(w) $$
To do so, I can consider the Lagrange's multipliers method, and thus set :
$$ L_\tau:(w,\lambda)\mapsto E_\tau(w) - \lambda[w^T\cdot w - 1] $$
I am not that familiar with this method, but I do know that we have to solve a system :
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\nabla_w L_t(w, \lambda) = 0 \\ 
\nabla_\lambda L_t(w, \lambda) = 0
\end{matrix}\right.
\Leftrightarrow 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
2 w^T\cdot D\cdot D^T - 2 x(\tau)\cdot D^T - 2\lambda w^T = 0 \\ 
1 - w^T\cdot w = 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Can someone gives me the next steps ? I can try to solve this system, but I would like to justify that the solution is the global minimum, and understand what I am doing so far.
N.B. In the paper, they use $L1$ normalization.
The paper : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318767684_Improved_Similarity-Based_Modeling_for_the_Classification_of_Rotating-Machine_Failures

Maybe I can reframe the problem by adding a constraint : || w ||² = 1 (euclidean norm, e.g.) and solve it with the method of the Lagrange's multipliers ?

I am having trouble understanding where regression comes in.
Informally, when doing regression, you are trying to learn a relation of the form, say, $Y = f(Z_1, \dots, Z_p) + \varepsilon$ between a dependent variable $Y$ and regressors $Z_1, \dots, Z_p$, with $\varepsilon$ being some noise that is independent of $Z_1, \dots, Z_p$.
What are the regressors, and what is your dependent variable?
By comparison, an estimation of $x(\tau)$ from $(x_1(\tau), \dots, x_n(\tau))$ is possible, for example with the empirical mean $\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i(\tau)$. Is this your goal?

That's a non-parametric model. You don't assume any functional shape. You rather try to find the best weights to explain a new observation $x(t)$ with the ones collected in $D$. You can quickly read this article : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318767684_Improved_Similarity-Based_Modeling_for_the_Classification_of_Rotating-Machine_Failures . You will see that they don't clearly justify the weight normalization with the L1 norm.

I just finished to correct the post, add details and edit the title to better illustrate the problem. Hope this help :) Don't hesitate to ask questions.
